# Compiling TypeScript code that references another yarn workspace

Tags: typescript, yarn-workspaces

I have a project structure like this:

```
myProject/
|- packages/
|  |- cli/
|  |  |- index.ts
|  |  |- package.json
|  |- core/
|  |  |- index.ts
|  |  |- function.ts
|  |  |- package.json
|-- package.json
```

> Not all files included (ie. tsconfig.json) for brevity

The `cli/` package consumes the `core` package by importing from `@myProject/core`. In each of their `package.json` files they care called `@myProject/cli` and `@myProject/core` respectively. I'm using yarn workspaces from the root of the project.

When I run the cli directly with `ts-node ./packages/cli` it works fine. However, when I compile the TypeScript to JavaScript I think the JavaScript code is still referencing the type script because I get the following error when trying to run the CLI js code:

```
> node build/cli/index.js
/Users/me/myProject/packages/core/index.ts:1 <-- pointing to TS??
export * from "./function";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

After compiling the TS to JS I have the same folder structure but under a root `build/` directory:

```
myProject/
|- build/
|  |- cli/
|  |  |- index.js --> referencing .ts instead of compiled JS core
|  |- core/
|  |  |- index.js
|  |  |- function.js
|- packages/
|  |- cli/
|  |  |- index.ts
|  |  |- package.json
|  |- core/
|  |  |- index.ts
|  |  |- function.ts
|  |  |- package.json
|-- package.json
```

Comment: How does your `package.json` and `tsconfig.json` look like for cli and core package?